# Google Streaming Speech Recognize Got Error "Aborted: error -83105"

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

When I use gRPC StreamingRecognize to recognize a wav file, some time I will got the following error. And I got no idea how to solve it.

```
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'START_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'END_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'START_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'END_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'START_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'END_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'START_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'END_OF_SPEECH' }
2016-08-20 11:32:36|17503|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: null,
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'END_OF_AUDIO' }
2016-08-20 11:32:37|17502|DEBUG|google_speech.js:94|data { error: { code: 10, message: 'Aborted: error -83105', details: [] },
results: [],
resultIndex: 0,
endpointerType: 'ENDPOINTER_EVENT_UNSPECIFIED' }
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?